# How to call a route & send data with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I've the following code

HTML

```
<div id="row">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" placeholder="Update your Post"></textarea>
</div>

<a href="#" id="btn-post" dusk="postButton" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPost">
  <span class="ion-plus-circled"> Post</span>
</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn-post").click(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var comment = $('textarea#comment').val();
    var postData = {
        post_content: comment.val();
        groupId: window.location.href.split("/")[4] // hack to get group id
    }

    console.log(postData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/post",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status){
        $("#addPost").modal('toggle');
            //window.location.href = data.redirectTo;                  
        }
    });
  });
});
```

web.php

```
Route::post('post', 'GroupController@post');
```

GroupController.php

```
public function post(Request $request){
    $post_content = $request->input('post_content');
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $groupId = $request->input('groupId');

    $post = PostGroup::firstOrNew(['group_id' => $groupId, 'post_content' => $post_content]);
    $post->user_id = $userId;

    $post->save();

    $redirectPath = '/groups/' . $groupId;
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Your post have been published! Take a look at',
        'redirectTo' => $redirectPath]);
}
```

What I want to do is to call the javascript function `btn-post` at the click of the link-button `Post`. This function takes the content of the `textarea` (which I don't know if I wrote correctly) and sends it to the `GroupController` using the same javascript function, to the route "/post", calling the function `post` (as defined in web.php), but for some reason it doesn't work, and I don't know where I was wrong (I think the problem is in the javascript function, as if it weren't called).

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I'm working with Sublime Text 3 and I don't have an output console where I can read errors. Anyway, everything starts from the javascript file, it's as if I had not imported it correctly, the Javascript has no effect.

Comment: When you go to the page with the form and open developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + I on Chrome). What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax and a logic error in your Javascript here:

```
var comment = $('textarea#comment').val();
var postData = {
    post_content: comment.val(); 
    groupId: window.location.href.split("/")[4] // hack to get group id
}
```

Logic error: you assign textarea value to the var `comment`. Then 2 lines after that, you call `comment.val()` on it, although it's a string at this point. No need to call `.val()` again.

Syntax error: you shouldn't use `;` within the `postData` JSON definition. You separate JSON fields with a comma.

This is the fix for the above 2 problems:

```
var postData = {
    post_content: comment, // <----
    groupId: window.location.href.split("/")[4] // hack to get group id
}
```

I suggest you start using developer tools to debug your Javascript

Comment: Problem solved, thank you so much! Anyway I'm a beginner and I don't know how to use a framework php as Laravel, I'm learning now and I make some mistakes. Could you suggest me some of these developer tools? Thank you in advance

Comment: They're implemented in every major browser, no external tools needed. You can open them pressing Crtl + Shift + I in Chrome or Firefox. Then go to the `console` tab and you will see your Javascript errors (and console output) there.